# Change WordPress language in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the wordpress language in functions.php. 
[WordPress change language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am0QA.png)

I tried with the below code.

```
function myprefix_live_site_locale( $locale ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/ar/') !== false) {
            return 'ar'; 
        } else {
            return 'tr_TR'; 
        }
    }
    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'myprefix_live_site_locale' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your script, it looks Okay. There are few changes need to change:

Change `strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/ar/')` to `strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/ar')`

and `return 'ar'` to `return 'ar_ar'`.

```
function myprefix_live_site_locale( $locale ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/ar') !== false) {
            return 'ar_ar'; 
        } else {
            return 'tr_TR'; 
        }
    }
    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'myprefix_live_site_locale' );
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar-ar" class="no-js no-svg">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">` It is getting updated but not actually works as changing in the CMS. (Not getting translated)

Comment: Thanks, Is there "-" or "_" in "ar-ar"?

Comment: `lang="ar-ar"` => -